# Is there a delay before the "change" event is triggered on select elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I've attached a "change" event listener on a `select` tag like this:

```js
var myoutput = document.getElementById("output");
document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change", function() {
  myoutput.textContent = "Change event triggered at " + (new Date());
}, false);
```

```html
<p id="output">Change select</p>
<select id="myselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

As you'll see if you try that snippet - there seems to be a noticeable delay after you change the `select` before the event handler is called. (Maybe 300ms or so?)

Is that because I'm doing something wrong? Is there a better way to implement this that eliminates this delay?

I know this seems like a minor issue, but the UI definitely seems sluggish and less responsive than it should.

Comment: I do not have issues with that snippet. As you JS runs on the client maybe he's the problem. On which devices are you testing the code and with which browser?

Comment: In Chorme I cannot see any delay, and I have never heard of such a thing. Have you tested it with different browsers?

Comment: Since computers have to obey the laws of physics nothing can happen instantly. Said that, it doesn't look sluggish in my 64-bit Firefox/44.0 on Windows 7. Does this snippet exhibit the actual issue or it only happens in your real app?

Comment: looks fine to me too

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. To be clear - I'm talking about a very slight delay - maybe 200-300ms or so. I do notice it in this snippet. It's more noticeable in Chrome (on a Mac) than in Safari (also on a Mac). I guess it must be minimal enough that most people won't notice it...